# Positioning a div underneath a (align-item) stretched div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I want to position a div below multiple flex-items using align-item: stretch; to make all the items the same height. And then no matter behind which div I place the new div it will be below the stretched height of the above div.

Current result
[image]

This is the current HTML

```
<ul class="flex-container stretch">
       <li class="flex-item"><img src="1.png" />
             <div class="info">
                    <div class="detail">
                           <div class="image">
                                        <img src="camera.png"/>
                           </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                           <div class="image">
                                        <img src="camera.png"/>
                           </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                           <div class="image">
                                        <img src="camera.png"/>
                           </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                           <div class="image">
                                        <img src="camera.png"/>
                           </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
       </li>
       <li class="flex-item"><img src="2.png" /></li>
       <li class="flex-item"><img src="1.png" /></li>
       <li class="flex-item"><img src="2.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

This is the current CSS i would like to also be able to wrap the images. And make the whole thing responsive.

```
.flex-container {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
       -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
       display: -webkit-box;
       display: -moz-box;
       display: -ms-flexbox;
       display: -moz-flex;
       display: -webkit-flex;
       display: flex;
       float: left;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.stretch { 
-webkit-align-items: stretch; 
       align-items: stretch; 
}
.flex-item{
       width: 23%;
       margin: 0 1%;
       background: orange;
}
.flex-item img{
width: 100%;
}
.info{
       padding:35px 0;
       width:100%;
       float:left;
       left:0;
       text-align:center;
       display:none;
       position:absolute;
       z-index:999;
       background: #fff;
}
.info .detail{
       width:25%;
       float:left;
}

.info image{
       width:65%;
}
```

Expected result

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you look for ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eEvYNR  Flex children elements, if no vertical margin else than 0 is applied, produces children of the to the same height to each rows. . I do not really understand your issue

Comment: Could you please add your answer like (answer not a comment) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set no vertical margins , elements should stretch by themselve and each item on a row will be the same `height`.

To show the second row of image beneath in `absolute`, you need to set the parent in `relative` so it becomes the reference for the size and coordonates.

Mind that each parent here is one average quart of the whole row and that margins are in between them.

The row to show will be an average of 400% `width` + XX% of `margin`s added all together.

To show it underneath, you can use `top:100%` and eventually add a `margin-top` to leave a gap.

```css
.flex-container {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
       -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
       display: -webkit-box;
       display: -moz-box;
       display: -ms-flexbox;
       display: -moz-flex;
       display: -webkit-flex;
       display: flex;
       float: left;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.stretch { 
/* this was defaut behavior */
}
.flex-item{
       width: 23%;
       margin: 0 1%;
       background: orange;
}
.flex-item img{
width: 100%;
}
/* =========================================================   update*/
.flex-item {
  position:relative;
}
.flex-item > img:hover ~ .info {
  top:100%;
  display:flex ;
}
.info{
       min-width:426%;
       top:100%;
/* =========================================================   end update */
       padding:35px 0;
       left:0;
       text-align:center;
       position:absolute;
       z-index:999;
       background: #fff;  
       display:none ;
}

.info .detail{
       min-width:25%;
       float:left;/* useless when parent is a flex box */
       margin:0  ;
}

.info image{/* !!! this rule does nothing. there is no tag image in your HTML structure */
       width:65%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container stretch">
       <li class="flex-item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/&text=Hover_me" />
             <div class="info">
                    <div class="detail">
                           <div class="image">
                                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/bad/&text=camera.png"/>
                           </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                           <div class="image">
                                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/0d8/&text=camera.png"/>
                           </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                           <div class="image">
                                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/456/&text=camera.png"/>
                           </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                           <div class="image">
                                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/f00/&text=camera.png"/>
                           </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
       </li>
       <li class="flex-item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/&text=2.png" /><br/> something more</li>
       <li class="flex-item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/&text=1.png" /></li>
       <li class="flex-item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/&text=2.png" /></li>
</ul>
```